# How can I add javascript to the head of an html document to listen for a click on an element not yet added to the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am using a third party web app that allows you to place your own code in the head of the HTML page. The rest of the document is auto-generated so the only place I can insert custom code is in the head before everything is added to the DOM.

I am trying to add click events to the various buttons that will be loaded in the DOM. I want the browser window to resize depending on the id of the button clicked.

I tried something like this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
window.onLoad=function(){
    document.getElementById("resize").onClick = window.resizeTo(250, 250);
    };
</script>
```

because I was hoping that if I used the onLoad event to add an onClick event it would wait until everything is loaded and I wouldn't get a null reference error. I don't get a null reference error, but the onClick doesn't work.

I tried to use jQuery also because one post I read suggested listening for all click events and then checking the id of the element that triggered the event, however I am not sure if I am using it correctly. This is the first time I've ever used jQuery. This didn't work either.

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).click(function() {
        if(event.target.id == 'resize') {
            window.resizeTo(250,250);
        };
    };
</script>
```

The real answer may just be that it isn't possible, but I am hoping there is some solution that I just haven't been able to find online.

To summarize, is there a way to resize the browser window based on the id of the element clicked inside of a third party web app? The script has to be in the head of the document before the elements are added to the DOM.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Try adding it in the body instead of the head.

Comment: @TylerH that's what he can't do. That's what the question is all about...

Comment: is `#resize` loaded using ajax or something..?

Comment: Yes that is correct. The rest of the document is auto-generated. The only place they let you put custom code is in the head.

Comment: I am using resizeTo() it's a javascript function.

Comment: So it's not working since the elements are added after page is loaded using ajax . refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24308705/2333214)  and delegate your click handler...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put your code in `document.ready` and delegate it to the element which may be added in the future. See http://api.jquery.com/on/ for more details.

```
 $(document).on("click", "selector of element added in future", function(){

 //execute your code
 });
```

Comment: Alok this is excellent it worked however the function executes as soon as the page loads and not on the click. I added it like so
$(document).on("click", "resize", window.resizeTo(250,250));

Comment: @Adam You need to wrap it in anonymous function, reread this answer. BTW, do you have really any element of type `resize`???

Comment: ooo right right. I always miss little things like that. I am still learning javascript. "resize" is just a dummy selector for a test page I was using.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can have a delegated event

```
$(document).on("click", "<selector>", function(){}));
```

which works for dynamically created objects as well.

as opposed to

```
$("<selector>").on("click", fucntion(){});
```

which will only work for original DOM elements.

Comment: I don't think we can delegate event using the shorthand `click`, this way `"selector"` will become ***event data***. We have to use `on` like this `.on('click', 'selector', function(){})`